# WPF Datagrid: Giving users the ability to sort columns, but not keep them sorted

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, sorting, wpfdatagrid

In my application, I have a datagrid that has values that are frequently updating.  I'd like the user to be able to click a column to sort, but continuously applying the sort will slow my application down significantly.  Is there any way to allow the user to do a one-time sort? They would click, the values would be sorted, but would not be re-sorted if the values changed.

Answer (score 2):

If you're binding the grid to a collection that implements **IList**, then under the covers the grid will create a **ListCollectionView** that it uses for sorting/filtering/grouping.  Fundamentally what you want to do is handle the *OnSorting* event of the DataGrid and tell the underlying view that you want to sort at that moment, but not later; unfortunately this isn't as easy as it appeared when I tried it.

This first approach was the following:

```
// Do a BeginInvoke here so that the grid can do its default sorting and we can take action after it's complete
this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)delegate()
{
    // Get the default view and clear the sort descriptions, but don't fire a refresh notification so that the grid
    // doesn't re-request the view/sorting
    ICollectionView dataView = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(((DataGrid)sender).ItemsSource);               
    dataView.SortDescriptions.Clear();
}, null);
```

The problem is that the Clear method tell the grid to refresh its view through the various property changed mechanisms.  The *DeferRefresh* method won't help here because the view will throw an exception if data is accessed; this is used for updating sorting on the entire collection.

I don't like it, but the best approach I can come up with is to apply your own custom sorting based on the user's action and apply it to the view yourself using the CustomSort property (though this may be harder with sorting multiple columns).

```
public class CustomComparer : IComparer
{
    public bool Ascending { get; private set; }
    public string Field { get; private set; }

    public CustomComparer(string fieldName, bool ascending)
    {
        this.Ascending = ascending;
        this.Field = fieldName;
    }

    public int Compare(object x, object y)
    {
        // Ideally check for identical types/etc and IComparable here

        PropertyInfo property = x.GetType().GetProperty(this.Field);
        IComparable val1 = property.GetValue(x) as IComparable;
        IComparable val2 = property.GetValue(y) as IComparable;

        return val1.CompareTo(val2) * (this.Ascending ? 1 : -1);
    }
}

private void DataGrid_OnSorting(object sender, DataGridSortingEventArgs e)
{
    ListCollectionView dataView = (ListCollectionView)CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(((DataGrid)sender).ItemsSource);

    // Assumes the column header is identical to field name
    bool ascending = true;
    string fieldName = e.Column.Header.ToString();

    // Check to see if we're reversing the sort
    CustomComparer comparer = dataView.CustomSort as CustomComparer;
    if (comparer != null && comparer.Field == fieldName)
        ascending = !comparer.Ascending;

    e.Column.SortDirection = ascending ? ListSortDirection.Ascending : ListSortDirection.Descending;
    dataView.CustomSort = new CustomComparer(fieldName, ascending);
    dataView.Refresh();
    e.Handled = true;
}
```

I don't like using reflection for the sorting, but it's the cleanest approach I could come up with without creating a sort object for each column.

Sorry about the long reply, I figured it would help explain my thought process and how I got here.